# Not Recognizing New Models When Trying to Load Data

Tags: django, postgresql, file-upload

I added a model in Django project after building my database.  It's PostgreSQL, not the standard SQLite. I run makemigations and migrate which both run fine.

My initial import line works. This runs:

```
from project import model1
```

When I try to load data into this model, I get the following error.

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "project_model1" does not exist
```

Not sure how to fix this. Do I need to delete the database and start again. I'm a newbie, please explain how to delete the Postgresql db in Django.

EDIT: When I run inspectdb, model is not there. It is there in the Migrations folder in the file 0001_inital.py

Comment: Have you migrate ?

Comment: Yes, I made migrations and migrated. Above edited for clarity.

Comment: How're trying to load data ? Can you verify the output once with `inspectdb` ?

Comment: Trying to load a csv with get_or_create(). It worked for my other datasets.

Comment: did you try running `model1.objects.all()` or `model1.objects.count()` ? if not then run and post the output.  Also you mentioned that you are a newbie, have to added your app in the `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: When I run inspectdb, the model is not there. When I look at the model under migrations - it is there.

Comment: can u post your `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS is not the problem as everything else in my project runs and works. Yes, its all installed properly.